# XORing two double variables

Tags: c++, double, xor

I wrote the following two lines :

Line 1 :

```
int a;
a=a^a;
```

Line 2 :

```
double d;
d=d^d;
```

Line 1 Works Fine But Line 2 Gives Me Error :

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator^’
```

Can Somebody tell me why the bit-wise **XOR operator** works on two **int** but doesn't work on two **double** variables...??

Seems like a silly doubt...but i really couldn't get through my program without this...!

Comment: And what would XORing two IEEE 754 doubles achieve exactly?

Comment: i was making an hashing algorithm...i wanted to XOR two 64 bit variables....so i tried to use a double....

Comment: you should use 64 bit integer uint64_t or long long, double makes no sense in this case

Comment: yup...Very useful idea u gave @chrmue thanx a lot..

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, It would allow for an in-memory value swap without declaring a temp variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the standard says so.

> #### C++11 §5.12 Bitwise exclusive OR operator
>
> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed; the result is the bitwise exclusive OR function of the operands. **The operator applies only to integral or enumeration operands.**

And it doesn't make much sense to xor two `double`s, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think 'the standard says so' is much of a reason, it doesn't explain why something is so.

Comment: There are some legitimate uses of XOR on `double` values. For example, if you know, that `s` is exactly either +1 or -1, and you need to calculate `s*a`, and you have standard IEEE 754 layout of the values, `s^a` gives the same result as `s*a`, but has lower latency on most CPUs. Also `std::copysign()` is usually implemented using XOR. There is a reason, why Intel added instructions like XORPS and XORPD to their SSE(2) instruction set.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers explained pretty well why its not supported by default. You should probably not do it, but here's how you **can** do it:

```
    double d = 12345.6789;
    unsigned long long* uPtr = (unsigned long long*)&d;
    unsigned long long uXor = (*uPtr) ^ (*uPtr);
    double dXor = *((double*)&uXor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because XOR, like other boolean bitwise operators is defined for binary operations, e.g. `0b10^0b01 = 0b11` but that doesn't make sense for anything where the representation is different from the value. If you XOR `4.0` and `1.0` should you get the XOR of the value, i.e. `5.0` or a bitwise XOR of the representation. If the former what do you do with values where the precision doesn't fully overlap e.g. '1.89e92`and`0.01`? Whilst the latter is difficult to even define (and likely meaningless) since the C++ standard doesn't define exactly how the double is represented and it may be represented differently during calculation and storage.

Comment: i cant find why the IEEE format has to intervene in bit wise XORing two variables of same size....all it has to do is take corresponding bits of two variables, XOR it and put back the result...whats the problem.....?

Comment: That's a bit of a sketchy reason. You can also XOR signed ints even though the C++ standard doesn't enforce two's complement. Every variable has a bit representation regardless of 'precision'.

Comment: @PRP: The question is 'what does it mean?' - you could bitwise the stored representation but it doesn't mean anything and it doesn't have any guaranteed consistent behaviour so why allow it? Doubly so, as you can do it trivially easily by simply casting a couple of time.

Comment: @PRP: where does this IEEE format come from? C++ doesn't mandate it. It could store your floats in trits.

Comment: While a single bitwise xor operation my have zero reasonable value when performed on floating point types, compound bitwise xor operations does have value. With three xor operations, you can switch the in-memory values of two variables of the same type, as long as both variables don't reside in the same memory location. Something like void Switch(ref double x, ref double y) would work without declaring temp variables if XOR worked on doubles.